# Get rid of a SwapBuffers error

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm coding a little program with Qt on Mac OS and this line appears at the end of each execution, I can't get rid of it, even after browsing Google to find a solution.

```
 QOpenGLContext::swapBuffers() called with non-exposed window, behavior is undefined
```

The message error is my the line of the execution log, repeated 2 or 3 times. Am-I missing something on closing QOpenGL routine?

I'll be glad to post a few line of code but I don't know which ones could be useful.

Comment: As with all such problems, you need a minimal test case. Copy your project, then start removing code that doesn't affect this error. Each time you remove something, compile and run and check if the error is still there. The test case that you post should be a single file (say `main.cpp`) with `#include "main.moc"` at the end.